# How to expose your project code to a Xcode playground when using cocoapods?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift-playground

In blog posts like https://useyourloaf.com/blog/adding-playgrounds-to-xcode-projects/, or the kickstarter source code http://github.com/kickstarter/ios-oss they add playground to xcode projects in order to have documentation + visual tests of the different view controllers and view components in the app.

The typical way they recommend to do it is like:

- Create a new framework target
- Add your code to the framework target (with the right access levels)
- Add a playground file to the workspace
- Build your framework
- Then the framework will be available within the playground.

This works without using cocoapods, but i have found that it's not the case when you **do** use cocoapods.

After adding a playground to the Xcode workspace, the Pods are available in the playground, but not my custom framework.

I don't understand how cocoapods work to make the pods available in the playground

I don't understand how internally playground decides which frameworks to have available for import, etc.

Does any of you have achieved this? have pointers to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is doable. In your `Podfile`, you need to declare targets for both your app and your framework, so that CocoaPods can add pods to both. Here is an example. You can check the tutorial [Using Playground](https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/113), [demo](https://github.com/onmyway133/UsingPlayground) and Medium post https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/playground-driven-development-in-swift-cf167489fe7b

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

use_frameworks!

pod 'Cheers'

target 'UsingPlayground'
target 'AppFramework'
```

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 13.2 this is much easier.

1. Open your app project, go to File > New > Playground.
2. In save window go to the dropdown where it says "Add to:", replace "Don't add to any project or workspace" with your project (See below). Hit Create.
   [image]
3. Open playground file within app project window
4. Import any pod/target from your app or use any class within the playground
5. Hit the Run/Play icon in the Playground, which will build your entire project first, and then run your playground code at the very end.